# YAML - Get contents of artifacts folder

Tags: yaml, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS S3 website, my yaml builds my site to a dist folder.

What I expect is for my website structure to look like this:

```
-root
    index.html
    etc...
```

Everything works fine, except my website structure ends up looking like this:

```
-root
    -dist
        index.html
        etc...
```

This is what my artifacts section of my yaml looks like:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'dist/**/*'
```

It seems, essentially, I do not want the dist folder to be my artifacts, I want the **CONTENTS** of the dist folder to be the artifacts.

It also seems that the flag to ignore paths flattens the entire system, which I do NOT want.  I just want to ignore that one folder `dist`, and get its contents, including subfolders, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need the 'base-directory' mapping:

Try this:

```
artifacts:
  base-directory: dist
  files:
    - '**/*'
```